# Passing an auth cookie conditionally to two sites on different web servers

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, forms-authentication

So, I have two sites that can be accessed from the same link, based on a condition I shall call 'Condition' from my main site:

```
if (Condition) {
    permission = true;
    window.location.href = 'http://Site1?CID=' + CtxCID;
    return;
    Destination = "site1";
} else {
    permission = true;
    window.location.href = 'http://site2?CID=' + CtxCID;
    return;
    Destination = "site2";
}
```

These sites are on seperate servers.  Site 1 is on a different server than site 2 and main site, which are both on the same server.

Site 1 and site 2 are largely identical: the difference is the database connection strings.

My main site uses an authentication cookie to ensure that the user stays logged in when you transfer over to site 2:

```
Private Sub AddAuthCookie(ByVal username As String)
    FormsAuthentication.Initialize()
    Dim expires As DateTime = DateTime.Now.AddDays(365)
    Dim ticket As FormsAuthenticationTicket = New FormsAuthenticationTicket(
        1,
        username,
        DateTime.Now,
        expires,
        True,
        "AUTHCOOKIE",
        FormsAuthentication.FormsCookiePath)

    Dim encryptedTicket = FormsAuthentication.Encrypt(ticket)

    Dim authCookie As HttpCookie = New HttpCookie(
        FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName,
        encryptedTicket)

    authCookie.Expires = expires

    Response.Cookies.Add(authCookie)

    Authenticated_hidden.Value = "True"
End Sub
```

The authentication part of the connection string for my main site:

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
    <forms name=".AUTH" loginUrl="~/Login.aspx" domain=".domain.com" enableCrossAppRedirects="true" requireSSL="false" />
</authentication>
```

The same this as above, except for my two child sites:

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
    <forms name=".AUTH" loginUrl="http://mysite.mydomain.com/Login.aspx" domain=".mydomain.com" enableCrossAppRedirects="true" />
</authentication>
```

This works great when it passes to site 2, which again, is on the same server as main site.  However, the cookie fails to keep me logged in when I go to site 1.

So, my question:

Does anyone with more experience with cookies than me have any idea what is going on here?  Keep in mind that I inherited this site from someone else: the relationship between main site and site 2 was already established.  I can provide more snippets of my code if needed.  Just ask!

UPDATE: The machine keys are set to be fixed, and are identical across all three sites.

Pic of cookie panel:
[image]

Comment: @Ashley Medway I added the picture of the cookie panel.  It's the same for all three

Comment: Thanks for added the cookie panel, as long as you are sure that the domain is `.mydomain.com`, then I am stumped.

Comment: @Ashley Medway would forms authentication cookies even be able to work across servers like this?